# How to make available on a PC, the RANDOM and URANDOM successor SRANDOM?

Tags: command-line, bash

SRANDOM is a more random replacement for the not so random RANDOM. It can be SRANDOM was released first time, on end of 2020. Additional, the SRANDOM can used for a bigger range of counts than RANDOM. [SRANDOM comes with Bash-5.1](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2020-12/msg00002.html).

So its the question, how to update to bash 5.1 or gettin SRANDOM support by other way ?

RANDOM:

- 16-bit
- create data which are not so equally distributed

SRANDOM:

- [SRANDOM manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/srandom.3p.html).
- 32-bit
- create data which are more equally distributed

What need to be installed or updated to make SRANDOM available on konsole of Ubuntu and how to install or update ?

And as an alternate for systems, which dont run bash 5.1 in future too, how to get and run the C code from SRANDOM implimentation in a bash script or on terminal ?

Comment: Can you wait 2 months?  It seems bash 5.1 is in Ubuntu 21.04 (See [this](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=bash).)  You can try installing it earlier, but I worry that it'll be fairly difficult given the potential number of dependencies...

Comment: @Ray, and as an allternate for systems, which dont run  bash 5.1 in future too, how to get and run the C code from SRANDOM implimentation in a bash script ?

Comment: I don't believe the SRANDOM variable in Bash 5.1 has anything to do with the /dev/srandom kernel module ...

Comment: Nor does it have anything to do with the srandom() function. So you're basically mixing 3 different things with the same name together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install by you application management, synaptics or by install the srandom supporting bash 5.1 p.e. on follow way:

wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-5.1.tar.gz

tar xf bash-5.0.tar.gz

cd bash-5.1

./configure
make

sudo make install

Answer (score 0):

The source-code for SRANDOM is available here https://github.com/josenk/srandom and you should be able to install on Linux with kernel 3.10 or above.

### Prerequisites

If you are into development or devops, you will probably have them already.

```
sudo apt install git make
```

### Download

The the source

```
mkdir your-srandom-source-code-dir
cd your-srandom-source-code-dir
git init
git clone https://github.com/josenk/srandom
```

### Install

The combo manual listed here https://github.com/josenk/srandom#compile-and-installation - but a brief example including installing a pre-requisite package:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install kernel-devel

cd your-srandom-source-code-dir
make
make install
```

### Use

You use SRANDOM as if it was an infinite file full of the desired random data, so for example, you can use it as a data-source for dd.  But avoid using commands which don't limit the amount of data they read (like "cat"), as this can cause performance issues.

```
dd if=/dev/srandom count=1 bs=1M of=random-output.txt
```

Comment: Would be neat if you explained your downvote...

Answer (score 0):

On systems which still dont support SRANDOM, you can use the follow, as better alternate to RANDOM, until your system supports SRANDOM:

```
rnd="$((0x$(dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/stdout bs=4 count=1 status=none | xxd -p)))"
```

A it can be, SRANDOM will be faster.

One othe alternate are:

```
my_rnd=$(openssl rand 4 | od -DAn)
```

Answer (score 0):

On systems which still dont support SRANDOM, you can build your own srandom replacement as follow:

```
srandom() {
   # should be random number from /dev/urandom
   # we take 4 bytes - one number 2^32
   echo "$((0x$(dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/stdout bs=4 count=1 status=none | xxd -p)))"
}
```